# Oracle SBC bridge 2 SIP calls

Tags: sip, voip

Is it possible to use just Acme/Oracle SBC for bridging 2 incoming SIP calls.(Using some HTTP api if it have it)

I'm quite proficient in VoIP, but I never used Acme/Oracle SBC. I think this is impossible, but maybe I'm wrong. If somebody know how to do this, some links to documentation will be very useful.

Comment: Please share the SBC Version.

Comment: Thank you for interest, but this question is more theoretical. Are there any Oracle/Acme SBC which can bridge calls? I don't have version of SBC, we plan to buy one.

Comment: I am from Contact Center background. I haven't got a chance to work on Oracle SBC, but our SIP Session Manager uses Oracle SBC as SIP providers. So SBC routes Incoming SIP calls to our Session Manager and We initiate Outbound calls from our dialler through SBC. So if you consider this as bridging , then yes SBC can bridge SIP call. Here is [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E81287_01/doc/sbc_scz740_aclireference.pdf) about SBC adminstration

Comment: No, by bridging I mean when 2 incoming calls are connected. So when 2 calls hit SBC they should be connected there, like conference, but only for 2 persons. I hope you understand my point. Nevertheless, thank you for help. ;)

Comment: This is not a commong SBC functionality but as I know it is supported by the mizu [sip sbc](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/SIPSBC.aspx). It is named as P2P (after phone to phone) and it works via a simple HTTP API (so you can trigger a call to 2 parties and once the second call is also connected, the 2 call leg will be interconnected.